# How to convert these objects to array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

How can I convert a string to a Typescript array?. Please help me.

Look at the code:

```
private validateEmptyOption(): any {
    console.log("CHECKED")
    let isValid = true;
    this.currentForm.sections.forEach((section: Section) => {
        section.fields.forEach((field: Field) => {
            debugger
            if (field.type === 'select') {
                console.log(field)

                const emptyOptionSections = JSON.parse(field.property).emptyOptionSections;

                if ((emptyOptionSections !== undefined) && (emptyOptionSections == null)) {
                    alert('QAZWSX');
                    isValid = false;
                }
             }
        return isValid;
        });
    });
}
```

This is my Result in console. I want do this convert to array and looping it.

[image: Check This]

Expected Result : There should be a validation message to inform that select controller cannot be empty

Actual Result : Form can save without any validation

Comment: What is the string that u want to convert to array?

Comment: @Plochie I attached it

Comment: Cant u just parse that string using JSON.parse?

Comment: Ok how can I do It. Can You help me. @Plochie

Comment: Do you want to convert `property` string from `fields` array to array?

Comment: Yes, convert property string from fields

Comment: `Object.keys()` and then `map` all keys and push key and values to new array using `myArray.push()`

Comment: Tried not working@GaurangDhorda

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, do not paste images of code - include them as text instead.

Comment: How to convert this thing to object, after taht valueswill be convert array and looping property: "{"type":"select","label":"Select","className":"form-control","name":"select-1577701474652","values":[{"label":"","value":"","selected":true},{"label":"","value":""}]}"

Comment: Please edit the question to include these changes instead of posting them as comments. Also, how should this 'object' look like? Have a look around and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use `validateEmptyOption(): boolean` you would get the hint, that your function does not return any value. The problem is your return statement if inside other functions thus not beeing return by the main one.

There is almost **never** a need to use ***any*** as a type with typescript. (Until you do very complicated things...)

```ts
function validateEmptyOption(): boolean {
    console.log("CHECKED")

    return this.currentForm.sections.every((section: Section) => {
        return section.fields.every((field: Field) => {
            debugger
            if (field.type !== 'select') {
                return false;
            }

            console.log(field)

            try {
                const emptyOptionSections = JSON.parse(field.property).emptyOptionSections;
                if ((emptyOptionSections !== undefined) && (emptyOptionSections == null)) {
                    alert('QAZWSX');
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }

            return true
        });
    });
}
```

The [`every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is used to check if for every value inner function returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `return` statement was written in the wrong place.
Check your `{` `}` `(` `)`